# Android Gradle: Version conflict of the google-services plugin after added firebase:firebase-core

Tags: java, android, gradle

So I added

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.0.1'
```

with the Firebase Assistant inside Android Studio to my gradle dependencies but after the sync I got an error message:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.
>   Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the google-services plugin (information about the latest version is available at https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.google.gms.google-services/) or updating the version of com.google.android.gms to 10.2.6.

and I don't know why. I'm using 10.2.6 from gms:play-service-ads. Here is my dependencies:

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile files('lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.6.jar')
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:10.2.6'
compile 'com.github.hani-momanii:SuperNova-Emoji:1.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.0.1'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please download latest google-services.json file from firebase console and add it in your project app directory. It will resolve your issue.

Comment: Btw. I accepted this answer because I had this issue, after re-clone, but the final solution was that Android studio added **10.0.1** of **firebase-core**, while **play-services-ads** is **10.2.6**. So I just changed **firebase-core** to **10.2.6**